# Encryption using modular addition and a key

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Problem i'm facing says:

```
 The value representing each row is encrypted using modular addition
with a modulus of 32 and a key of 27.
```

I sort of figured out what modular addition is for myself an hour ago but the key thing confuses me.

What does this

> key of 27

mean? And how do I find out the original value in the very end?

Text of the task

> The image in Figure 1 is to be encoded and encrypted using the
>   following steps. 1 Each of the five horizontal rows of the picture is
>   encoded as a 5-bit binary number. White squares are encoded as 0s and
>   black squares as 1s. The top row is therefore encoded as 00010. 2
>   Starting from the left, the first digit is multiplied by 16, the
>   second by 8, the third by 4, the fourth by 2, and the fifth by 1. For
>   the first row the result is (0 × 16) + (0 × 8) + (0 × 4) + (1 × 2) +
>   (0 × 1)
>   = 0 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 0
>   = 2. 3 The value representing each row is encrypted using modular addition with a modulus of 32 and a key of 27. 4 The result is
>   converted to a 5-bit binary number. 5 The binary number corresponding
>   to one row of the original picture is then used to fill a
>   corresponding row in a blank grid. 1s are displayed as black squares
>   and 0s are displayed as white squares. Choose from the options below
>   the one pattern that represents the correctly encoded and encrypted
>   image.

Thanks in advance xx

Comment: There is nothing else stated like an algorithm (RSA, ...) or section heading or something else? Regards

Comment: no sir. Nothin'

Comment: Well, looks like you just posted the algorithm, so now it should make more sense! :-) Thanks

Comment: If it does - great! Please help :)

Comment: unfortunately not. it is 5*5 grid with a number '4' displayed in pixels

Comment: Looks like someone got it and posted an answer. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider alphabet of 32 letters:

'  ' = 0;
'a' = 1;
'b' = 2;
'c' = 3;
. . .
'v' = 22;
'w' = 23;
'x' = 24;
'y' = 25;
'z' = 26;
 and other symbols - up to 31:
'+' = 27;
'-' = 28;
'(' = 29;
')' = 30;
'=' = 31.

Now, encrypt the text $-$ is to add value 27 to each symbol value:

Let **plain text** is "a+b=c".
Digital interpretation: (1,27,2,31,3).

Encryption:

$1+27 \equiv 28 \mod 32$;
$27+27 \equiv 22 \mod 32$;
$2+27 \equiv 29 \mod 32$;
$31+27 \equiv 26 \mod 32$;
$3+27 \equiv 30 \mod 32$;

So, **cipher text** is $(28,22,29,26,30)$. Of, in letter format: "-v(z)".

---

**Edit.**

If you need to encrypt black/white images like

$\Box\Box\Box\blacksquare\Box \;,\; \Box\blacksquare\Box\blacksquare\blacksquare \;,\;$ ...

then same way:

1-st symbol: $00010_2 = 2_{10}$; $\quad$ $2+27\equiv 29 \mod 32$; $\quad$ encrypted : $29_{10}=11101_2$;

2-nd symbol: $01011_2 = 11_{10}$; $\quad$ $11+27\equiv 6 \mod 32$; $\quad$ encrypted : $6_{10}=00110_2$;

So, encrypted image will look like this:

$\blacksquare\blacksquare\blacksquare\Box\blacksquare \;,\; \Box\Box\blacksquare\blacksquare\Box \;,\;$...

---

Finally, to decrypt, it is necessary to subtract $27$, or (the same) to add $5$ (because $32-27=5$).

Comment: so basically the key - means the shift? say C is the encrypted value and P is the value being encrypted and K is a key value then C ≡ (P + K) mod 32 ??

Comment: Your answers are awesome. Thanks a lot Oleg. Btw, is my assumption above correct?

Comment: Yes, I think $C \equiv (P+K) \mod 32$. Like Vigenère cipher with constant key $K=27$.

Comment: @Dennis:  that seems to be correct.  Each row is a binary number, you add $27$ and take the result $\pmod {32}$ then make it black and white squares.

Comment: You're welcome :)